# easymock replacement for setReturnValue

Tags: easymock

Hy,

The new version of easymock has deprecated the `setReturnValue` method from `org.easymock.MockControl`

is there a way to set a default return value for a call, or do I have to use `expect(...)` instead ?

I also want to mention that except for this method that I want to return a default value (any given number of times), the other methods have to be strict (ordering and call count matters)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do

```
expect(mock.getterMethod()).andStubReturn(retValue);
```

The checkOrder is only necessary if you are on a strict mock (or if checkOrder(true) was called).

Comment: you are right checkOrder is only necessary for strict mock, i added it because i mostly need either a strict mock or complete freedom

Answer (score 0):

just noticed the addition of other useful features to expect

a solution to my problem can look like this:

```
mockCtrl.checkOrder(false);
expect(mock.getterMethod()).andReturn(retValue).anyTimes();
mockCtrl.checkOrder(true);
```

it's still a bit more than before (in code size) but it's a solution